# How to do page view with cross fade animation

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

I am making a **carousel** with **cross fade animation** which I am using **AnimatedSwitcher** with **FadeTransition** to achieve such effect. The effect is fine but I want the carousel to be **swipeable**. I had tried PageView but I ***do not*** want the ***slide animation***. Does anyone have any solution to this? Please Help. Thanks in advance.

The custom carousel I currently use.

```
AnimatedSwitcher(
      duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      transitionBuilder: (Widget child, Animation<double> animation) {
        return FadeTransition(child: child, opacity: animation);
      },
      child: Image.asset(
        imageList[currentIndex.toInt()],
        key: ValueKey<int>(currentIndex),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not want slide animation, do not use `PageView`.

Stick with your current implementation with `AnimationSwitcher`. If you want to add gesture support, wrap it with `GestureDetector` and listen on the `onHorizontalDrag...` or `onVerticalDrag...` events.